# PHP can eval() access outside variable?

Tags: php, eval

Im a student studying PHP, Java. but I don't know if eval can access outside variable.

My code :

```html
<?php
$o = "This is just test character";

$code = "echo $o;"

eval($code);
?>
```

does it active? if not, how can i make it to active? (my purpose is eval() can access outside variable..)

sorry for my bad english and thx for listening.

Comment: Is the content of `$o` shown when you run the code?

Comment: eval() can access whatever it wants in the PHP-file, and also quite a bit more. Hence why you really shouldn't be using eval() for anything unless you have to, and know how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the obvious missing `;` on line 2

The issue you're having with eval is the string you're passing is not valid PHP.

```
<?php
$o = "This is just test character";
$code = '<?php echo $o;';
eval('?>'.$code);
```

- https://3v4l.org/CHkR3

And if you're using double quotes it will parse into the string and again create invalid PHP by missing the quotes.

```
<?php
$o = "This is just test character";
$code = "<?php echo '$o';";
eval('?>'.$code);
```

- https://3v4l.org/CHkR3

**Bottom line, if you don't know how eval works then you should definitely not use it.**

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php => "The code must not be wrapped in opening and closing PHP tags"

Comment: The way I'm doing it makes it work in a natural way, else you would need to strip out the staring `<?php` in any code `include()'ed` or stored in db etc, PHP should always start with `<?php` regardless whether it's going through eval or not. **The quote in the manual is just pointing out it won't as expected by passing php into the function, thats why im doing** `?>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the string in the $code variable between aposthropes and then it'll work. Like this:

```
$o = "'This is just test character'";
$code = "echo $o;";
eval($code);
```